# Getting "ViCommand: no such keymap" errors while using Term::Readline:Zoid

Tags: perl, ubuntu, readline

I have a simple bit of code that works well until I export

```
PERL_RL='Zoid default_mode=ViCommand'
```

in order to use vi mode while editing.  When I test the code I'm getting the error: ViCommand: no such keymap.  I installed libterm-readline-zoid-perl and from what I can tell ViCommand is built in so I should be good to go but apparently not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term = new Term::ReadLine 'LineEdit';

while ( defined ($_ = $term->readline($ARGV[0],$ARGV[1])) ) {
    print $_;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Try use `default_mode=command` instead of  `default_mode=ViCommand`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no command named `ViCommand`. However, by inspecting the [source](https://metacpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Zoid/source/lib/Term/ReadLine/Zoid.pm#L80), see line 80:

```
command => { _use => 'Term::ReadLine::Zoid::ViCommand'  },
```

you should be able to use "ViCommand" line editing by setting the environment variable `PERL_RL` like this:

```
PERL_RL='Zoid default_mode=command'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```perl
$term->parse_and_bind("set editing-mode vi");
```